# Physical meaning of the dot product of a vector and its laplacian

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, physics, inner-products, laplacian

What is the physical meaning of $$\boldsymbol{A}\cdot (\nabla^2\boldsymbol{A})$$ where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a vector field in 3D space?

What does it show?

Comment: Does this question come from anywhere in particular? (e.g. The vector Laplacian shows in Naviar Stokes, but not like this).

Comment: If we consider velocity vector, then this term appears in the divergence of Lamb vector (divergence of incompressible Navier-Stokes).